# how can I send emails from facebookmail to my app users?

Tags: facebook, email

i would like to send my app users an email from Facebookmail,   i have received such email from another app and i would like to do the same for my app users.
the email I have received was from this sender 
 "apps+kr4m4XXXXX5x@facebookappmail.com"

can someone please advise how it can be done? ( I'm aware that i can send them email directly but im looking to send them directly from facebookmail..?)
* another point to mention is by clicking "unsubscribe" link on the email - this is the link :

http://www.facebook.com/n/?editaccount.php&notifications&block=376XXXXXX2389556&t=1366XXXXX53&l=b&mid=7ddd6d3G5af3eff255b6G0G27&bcode=1.136XXXXX853.AbkyMvZyA7-3FDDD&n_m=my_email@url.com

therefore I'm pretty sure it can be done....
anyone???

** ( the XXXXX i added in order not to recognize the sender )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the REST API which will be deprecated. Unfortunately it's not possible to send emails via Facebook through GRAPH API.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/

the link above is broken

it looks like this

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/notifications.sendEmail?recipients=USER_ID&subject=YOUR_SUBJECT&text=YOUR_EMAIL_BODY&callback=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
```